# hibernate behavior explanation:

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have 3 code snippets:

1:

```
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Prepod prepod = (Prepod) session.load(Prepod.class, 1l);
        Student student = (Student) session.load(Student.class, 1l);

        Hibernate.initialize(prepod.getStudents());
        Hibernate.initialize(student.getPrepods());

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.flush();
        session.close();
            List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
     students.add(student);

     List<Prepod> prepods = new ArrayList<Prepod>();
     prepods.add(prepod);

     prepod.setStudents(students);
     student.setPrepods(prepods);


     session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
     session.beginTransaction();
     session.update(student);

     session.getTransaction().commit();
     session.close();
```

First snippet works and I saw so log:

```
Hibernate: select prepod0_.id as id1_1_1_, prepod0_.name as name2_1_1_, students1_.prepods_id as prepods1_1_3_, student2_.id as students2_2_3_, student2_.id as id1_0_0_, student2_.age as age2_0_0_, student2_.name as name3_0_0_ from prepod prepod0_ left outer join prepod_Student students1_ on prepod0_.id=students1_.prepods_id left outer join Student student2_ on students1_.students_id=student2_.id where prepod0_.id=?
Hibernate: select student0_.id as id1_0_1_, student0_.age as age2_0_1_, student0_.name as name3_0_1_, prepods1_.students_id as students2_0_3_, prepod2_.id as prepods1_2_3_, prepod2_.id as id1_1_0_, prepod2_.name as name2_1_0_ from Student student0_ left outer join prepod_Student prepods1_ on student0_.id=prepods1_.students_id left outer join prepod prepod2_ on prepods1_.prepods_id=prepod2_.id where student0_.id=?
Hibernate: update Student set age=?, name=? where id=?
```

2:delete from 1

```
            Hibernate.initialize(prepod.getStudents());
        Hibernate.initialize(student.getPrepods());
```

and we have:

```
 Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Prepod prepod = (Prepod) session.load(Prepod.class, 1l);
    Student student = (Student) session.load(Student.class, 1l);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.flush();
    session.close();
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
 students.add(student);

 List<Prepod> prepods = new ArrayList<Prepod>();
 prepods.add(prepod);

 prepod.setStudents(students);
 student.setPrepods(prepods);


 session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
 session.beginTransaction();
 session.update(student);

 session.getTransaction().commit();
 session.close();
```

result:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
    at logic.Prepod_$$_javassist_1.setStudents(Prepod_$$_javassist_1.java)
    at logic.Main.main(Main.java:43)
```

3:more delete

```
session.close();
```

and

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

Thus we have:

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Prepod prepod = (Prepod) session.load(Prepod.class, 1l);
        Student student = (Student) session.load(Student.class, 1l);
session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.flush();
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        students.add(student);

        List<Prepod> prepods = new ArrayList<Prepod>();
        prepods.add(prepod);

        prepod.setStudents(students);
        student.setPrepods(prepods);
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(student);


        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
```

result of this code:
it works and I see so log:

```
Hibernate: select prepod0_.id as id1_1_1_, prepod0_.name as name2_1_1_, students1_.prepods_id as prepods1_1_3_, student2_.id as students2_2_3_, student2_.id as id1_0_0_, student2_.age as age2_0_0_, student2_.name as name3_0_0_ from prepod prepod0_ left outer join prepod_Student students1_ on prepod0_.id=students1_.prepods_id left outer join Student student2_ on students1_.students_id=student2_.id where prepod0_.id=?
Hibernate: select student0_.id as id1_0_1_, student0_.age as age2_0_1_, student0_.name as name3_0_1_, prepods1_.students_id as students2_0_3_, prepod2_.id as prepods1_2_3_, prepod2_.id as id1_1_0_, prepod2_.name as name2_1_0_ from Student student0_ left outer join prepod_Student prepods1_ on student0_.id=prepods1_.students_id left outer join prepod prepod2_ on prepods1_.prepods_id=prepod2_.id where student0_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into prepod_Student (prepods_id, students_id) values (?, ?)
```

Especially note for this line:

```
Hibernate: insert into prepod_Student (prepods_id, students_id) values (?, ?)
```

This behavior doesn't understand for me. Can you explain me why I saw these results?

**UPDATE**
Prepod:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "prepod")
public class Prepod {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Column
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long i) {
        id = i;
    }
```

Student:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
public class Student {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Long age;
    private List<Prepod> prepods = new ArrayList<Prepod>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Prepod> getPrepods() {
        return prepods;
    }

    public void setPrepods(List<Prepod> prepods) {
        this.prepods = prepods;
    }

    public Student() {
        name = null;
    }

    public Student(Student s) {
        name = s.getName();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Column(name = "age")
    public Long getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setId(Long i) {
        id = i;
    }

    public void setName(String s) {
        name = s;
    }

    public void setAge(Long age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate wraps lazy loaded collections and objects with its custom `proxies`, `HibernateProxy`. Each of these has a `LazyInitializer` instance to initialize the object (because it wasn't fully loaded yet).

These `LazyInitializer` instances extend `AbstractLazyInitializer`.

The method `AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize()` has the following (which interests us)

```
public final void initialize() throws HibernateException {
    if ( !initialized ) {
        if ( specjLazyLoad ) {
            specialSpecjInitialization();
        }
        else if ( session == null ) {
            throw new LazyInitializationException( "could not initialize proxy - no Session" );
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

In your **first** snippet, you call

```
Hibernate.initialize(prepod.getStudents());
Hibernate.initialize(student.getPrepods());
```

before closing the `Session`, which initializes the Hibernate `proxies`, ie. `prepod` and `student` objects. So their `initialized` flag is set to true and all future interactions with the object skip the `if` block.

In your **second** snippet, you don't initialize the `proxies` and close the `Session`. When you try to call

```
prepod.setStudents(students);
```

It will fail, because `initialized` is false and the `session` is `null`

```
else if ( session == null ) {
    throw new LazyInitializationException( "could not initialize proxy - no Session" );
}
```

In your **third** snippet, you don't close the `Session` so the call to

```
prepod.setStudents(students);
```

will just do initialization uninterrupted.

Comment: In all examples I use  EAGER initialization. I think it loads relation collection.

Comment: @user2674303 Go ahead and post your entity mappings.

Comment: @User You are in a better position to check than I am, but Hibernate stills proxies your class even if you have EAGER-ly loaded collections.

Comment: @user2674303 Use a debugger. You will notice the class type of your `prepod` reference is actually a proxy of type `Prepod_$$_javassist_1`.